# How would I fill MAX MIN bullets in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I want to fill the bullets of highcharts just like the bar of the highchart.
Please help me if anyone has knowledge of highcharts.
This is highchart function which I am using.
I want to make the first colour as the first bar as the second color as the second bar.
If you know any solution then please let me know. Thank you

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo:'DimensionsChartfirst',
                type:'column'
            },
            colors: ['#0070C0', '#C00000'],
           title: {
                text: 'Office data'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            credits:{enabled:false},
            legend:{
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow:false,
                    borderWidth:0
                }
            },
            xAxis:{
            categories: [
                    'Weight',
                    'Height'
                ],
                lineColor:'#999',
                lineWidth:1,
                tickColor:'#666',
                tickLength:3,
                title:{
                    text:'Part Counts'
                }
            },
            yAxis:{
                lineColor:'#999',
                lineWidth:1,
                tickColor:'#666',
                tickWidth:1,
                tickLength:3,
                gridLineColor:'#ddd',
                title:{
                    text:'Office data',
                   // rotation:90,
                    margin:10
                }
            },    
            series: [{
                        name: 'MAX',
                data: MaxVal,
                colors: ['#0070C0'],
                type: 'column',
                colorByPoint: true
            },{
                        name: 'MIN',
                data: MinVal,
                colors: ['#C00000'],
                type: 'column',
            colorByPoint: true
            }]

        });
```

[image: How would I fill these MAX MIN bullets in highcharts]

Comment: To sum up: remove the `colorByPoint` property from your series object, and replace the `colors` array with the `color` single-value property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
series: [{
                name: 'MAX',
                data: MaxVal,
                color: '#0070C0'

            },{
                name: 'MIN',
                data: MinVal,
                color: '#C00000'

            }]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to remove `colorByPoint: true` properties in your series.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4zu28aqk/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.colorByPoint